# ADF Copy Activity Issue

Tags: azure-data-factory, azureportal

I am using Copy Activity in ADF to copy data from SQL. But In one of the table's column there is an HTML code so when the data get copied in CSV file the HTML code got spread across other rows.

My Sink Properties are:

```
Delimiter = Pipe
Row Delimiter = Default
Encoding = Default
Quote Character = "
Escape Character = \
```

I want the html code to not spread across other rows. So how could I possibly fix it?

Comment: CSVs are always trickier. I would say do a dumb copy of it. Do not specify the first row as the header or any additional configuration. And then in your downstream application handle the CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the html code gets split across multiple rows is because, the data in that column has row delimiter character (`\n`).

While copying from sql table to csv file, you have given the property `Quote Character = "`. This will make sure to enclose the data within double quotes `(")`, when the data has any delimiter in that. The same settings `Quote Character = "`, you can use while reading this csv file for downstream activities. This will make sure the data is read correctly, without getting divided across the rows.

I have tried with sample data and below are the observations.

- Source data is taken in SQL table.
  [image]
- After copying data to pipe delimited file, data in code got divided in different rows.
  [image]

Since the settings is given as `quote character="`, the value for code is enclosed within double quotes `(")`.

- When using for downstream activities, if same settings is used, data will be stored as given in source sql table.
  [image]

Comment: Apologies for late reply but can you try to load the csv file in dataframe? Because When I try to load it in spark dataframe the html code gets in ID column.

Comment: Can you share me the code that you use to load csv in df?

Comment: I was using spark.read.csv("path",sep='|',header=True). I guess it will work fine with multiLine = True

Comment: Yes, `Multiline=True` [img](https://i.imgur.com/aODQbmN.png) works